# jQuery Tablesorter Not Sorting List of Filenames

Tags: jquery, python, sorting, filenames, tablesorter

I am using Python to read a folder on my computer and create a list containing dictionaries for each file in that folder. The dictionary contains values for the file name, modified time, size and type.

I then display the contents of my list in an HTML table (with Django template tags):

```
{% for file in file_list %}
    <tr>
        <td class="name">{{file.name}}</td>
        <td class="kind">{{file.kind|upper}}</td>
        <td class="date">{{file.uploaded|date:"j/m/Y g:i A"}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Sorting works fine for the "kind" and "uploaded" columns, but not for the "name" column. The table is sorted alphabetically in ascending order on the "name" column, however. What I am trying to achieve here is to allow the table to be sorted on the "name" column in descending order. I can't seem to get it to work. Perhaps the Windows OS has given these files an inherent order? What am I missing here?

Comment: By this time the name is just a string isn't it.  I guess you have something else not set correctly.

Comment: @user2310289 That's what I thought. I guess I'll have a look at my code again.